# How to repeat the same function for each slide of a carousel when loading a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image carousel that has several slides and each of them has a title and a button.

Each button (`.meta-description`) links to a different page, and I want the corresponding title (`.meta-title`) of that slide to link to the same page the button goes to. (e.g. slide 1/title 1/link 1, slide 2/title 2/link 2, etc).

I managed to do part of the process with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a_href = $('.meta-description a').attr('href');
  $('.meta-title').wrapInner('<a href="'+a_href+'" />');
});
```

But the problem is, now ALL slide titles link to the href of the first slide button (link 1).

How can I repeat the function for each slide so the titles match their corresponding button href?

---

UPDATE:
This is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="meta">
         <div class="meta-title">Title 1</div>
         <div class="meta-description">
            <a>Link 1</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="meta">
         <div class="meta-title">Title 2</div>
         <div class="meta-description">
            <a>Link 2</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="meta">
         <div class="meta-title">Title 3</div>
         <div class="meta-description">
            <a>Link 3</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All slides use the same class, same goes for titles, and descriptions, so there's no id to "match" them to their corresponding title and link. The only distinction is that a new class (`.active-slide`) gets appended to the active slide while the others get an additional style of `visibility: hidden`.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: Cant really do much helping without knowing your DOM structure

Comment: Noted. Added the HTML @m_callens , hope that's enough info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.each`, it will iterate over each element that matches the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.meta-description').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).prev('.meta-title').wrapInner('<a href="'+href+'"></a>');
  });
});
```

- Inside the function, you use `$(this)` to reference the current element.
- First you use `$(this).find('a')...` to get to the `a` tag [inside the current element](https://api.jquery.com/find/).
- Then you use `$(this).prev('.meta-title')...` to get to the `.meta-title` that is the [preceding sibling of the current element](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

**See code snippet below for a demo:**
In the code snippet I changed `$(this).find('a').attr('href')` to `$(this).find('a').html()`, based on the HTML you provided.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.meta-description').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').html();
    $(this).prev('.meta-title').wrapInner('<a href="'+href+'"></a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="meta-title">Title 1</div>
      <div class="meta-description">
        <a>Link 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="meta-title">Title 2</div>
      <div class="meta-description">
        <a>Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="meta-title">Title 3</div>
      <div class="meta-description">
        <a>Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a79zwds2/*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, all the slide titles keep linking to the first slide's link. I added the HTML for reference in case it helps.